# How can I display a tkinter loading screen while I wait for my program to launch?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program and the very first thing that happens before the login page is displayed is some web scraping and a few database queries. I run this straight away, I want to display a loading screen in the time before the login page is displayed.

Straight away this class is ran:

```
class login():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self._LoginUsername = StringVar() #PRIVATE
        self.createwidgets(master)

        organise = ORGANISE_DATABASE()
```

the organise database class just does all the technical stuff, when this is complete it then opens my tkinter window. How could I display a loading window - just a simple screen saying 'loading' - in the time that this organise class is ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tkinter [toplevel](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-toplevel-widget/). Toplevel allows you to create a window on top of other Tkinter windows, or create another window before your main window appears.

So, you could:

```
class login():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self._LoginUsername = StringVar() #PRIVATE
        self.createwidgets(master)

        top = Toplevel() #Assuming you did from tkinter import *
        top.geometry("180x100")
        top.title("Loading Screen")
        Label(top, text = "The app is loading now.").pack()

        top.update() #Update loading screen so it doesn't freeze

        organise = ORGANISE_DATABASE() #Do loading

        top.destroy() #Destroy loading screen after loading complete
```

You can create other tkinter widgets on your loading screen, if you wanted a loading bar you could update it during your `ORGANISE_DATABASE()` function. If the function is longer than a few seconds, you might want to `update()` your toplevel loading window within it to stop it freezing.